# How can I use browserContext in the playwright test runner?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I'm using playwright to test a PWA (Progressive Web App) and I want to test the offline behavior.

browserContext has a [setOffline](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-set-offline) method.

When calling playwright as a library, I can set `browserContext` like this:

```
// example.js
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
    channel: 'msedge',
  });
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.microsoft.com/edge');
  await context.setOffline(true);
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

But for my PWA, I'm using the bundled playwright test runner.

I have configured my test runner to use 5 devices-- desktop Chrome, Firefox, and Webkit, as well as mobile Webkit and mobile Chrome.  I want to enter and exit offline mode in all of them within the test to confirm my PWA's behavior.

How can I set `browserContext` in the test runner?  It doesn't seem to be available within the test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never actually tried this, but as I see it, just taking the context instance into the async function should be fine:

```
test('context', async({ page, context }) => {
    await page.goto('https://www.microsoft.com/edge');
    await context.setOffline(true);
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be even possible in config itself, something like that :

```
testDir: 'testStaging',
  use: {
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    baseURL: process.env.SITE,
    contextOptions: {offline: true},
    httpCredentials: {
      username: ???,
      password: ???,
    },
  },
```

For example, this is my solution. After using this, you have probably defined all projects, so your five devices/browsers and this will be valid for all of them.